# How can i get full url to include in newsletter sent with Symfony2?

Tags: url, symfony, permalinks, swiftmailer

I'm going to use Symfony2 to sent periodically a newsletter to many users. I've to include a permalink to the HTML email for those who experience problems in reading them with an email client.

Anyway, assuming that i'm sending the newsletter this way:

```
// Assume success and create a new SentMessage to store and get permalink
$sent = new SentMessage();

$sent->setRecipients(/* ... */);
$sent->setSubject(/* ... */);
$sent->setContent(/* ... */);

// Get the slug for the new sent message
$slug = $sent->getSlug(); // Like latest-product-offers-546343

// Construct the full URL
// e.g. http://mydomain.com/newsletter/view/latest-product-offers-546343

// Actually send a new email
$mailer->send(/* .. */);
```

How can i construct the full URL (domain + controller + action + slug) to include it in a new email?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

With the [router](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#generating-absolute-urls), of course

> By default, the router will generate relative URLs (e.g. `/blog`). To
>   generate an absolute URL, simply pass `true` to the third argument of
>   the `generate()` method:

Perhaps your code might look like this

### Symfony2

```
$url = $router->generate(
    'slug_route_name',
    array('slug' => $sent->getSlug()),
    true // This guy right here
);
```

### Symfony3

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

$url = $router->generate(
    'slug_route_name',
    array('slug' => $sent->getSlug()),
    UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL // This guy right here
);
```

Comment: Amazing. So long time to learn Sf2 and never heard about full url generation. Thanks Peter, you always help us.

Answer (score 16):

Update with Symfony 3:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

$this->generateUrl('blog_show', array('slug' => 'my-blog-post'), UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
// http://www.example.com/blog/my-blog-post
```

Answer (score 7):

**TWIG**

If this is within a twig template, use `url('your route')` instead of `path('your route')` to get the absolute URL.