# How can i get the absolute url of route with symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

I am using symfony and I want to get the url of a specific `route` ,
my `route` is like this

```
project_sign_in:
    pattern:  /signin
    defaults: { _controller: ProjectContactBundle:User:signIn }
```

i want to generate the url from this route so i can get

`localhost/app_dev.php/signin`
or `{SERVER-ADDRESS}/app_dev/signin`

if I was browsing the server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i get full url to include in newsletter sent with Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621068/how-can-i-get-full-url-to-include-in-newsletter-sent-with-symfony2)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The last facultative parameter has to be true to generate absolute url:

```
$router->generate('project_sign_in', array(), true);
```

in twig:

```
{{ path('project_sign_in', {}, true) }}
{# or #}
{{ url('project_sign_in') }}
```

in controller:

```
$this->generateUrl('project_sign_in', array(), true );
```

EDIT: for symfony 4, see @Michael B. answer
`UrlGenerator->generate('project_sign_in', [], UrlGenerator::ABSOLUTE_URL);`

Comment: from symfony 4 on, please see @MiachalB's answer

Answer (score 25):

Using the Routing Component at version 4.0:

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator;

UrlGenerator->generate('project_sign_in', [], UrlGenerator::ABSOLUTE_URL);
```

Comment: worked perfectly... @goto solutions did not work for me

Answer (score 8):

In Symfony 5.0, if you are using Routing within a service:

```
namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
.
.
.
private $router;

public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router)
{
    $this->router = $router;
}

public function foo()
{
    $this->router->generate('bar', [], urlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At least with Symfony 6, the controller has a builtin method ready for that:

```
$signUpPage = $this->generateUrl('sign_up');
```

See https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#generating-urls-in-controllers

Comment: And if you want an absolute URL instead of an absolute path, you should pass the third argument to the call as in `$this->generateUrl('project_sign_in', [], UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);`