# Symfony generate full URL

Tags: symfony

I need to generate full URL with symfony, for now I have :

```
$this->generateUrl('my_route', array('type' => 'param')
```

This function generate something like : `/my_project/xxxxxxxxx`

Is there a function like `generateUrl` for generate a fully URL ? I need the HTTP and the domain name.

I know I can add them manually but If there is a function for that it's better.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i get full url to include in newsletter sent with Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621068/how-can-i-get-full-url-to-include-in-newsletter-sent-with-symfony2)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is quite easy:

```
$this->generateUrl('my_route', array('type' => 'param'), UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
```

Don't forget to add:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is do it:

```
   $this->generateUrl('my_route',  array('type' => 'param'), true);
```

Comment: What about the symfony-devs chaning the api, and as such the value of `UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL`?  Interfaces exist for a reason.

Comment: this option was for Symfony versions before 2.7

Comment: Indeed - this option was for older versions of symfony. I just checked the latest docs

Comment: I'm using Symfony3 and it's ok

Comment: Even before Symfony 2.7 using the constants did work and should always be preferred (starting with Symfony 2.8 not using them will trigger deprecations and in Symfony 3.0 the constant values have been changed to be integers.